# Not able to get 2 decimal places in Hive query using Hue editor

Tags: hive, hue

I am writing Hive query in the Hue editor in Cloudera VM. But somehow I am not getting the data in 2 decimal places. Same code if I run on shell it gives correct result. I am using latest cloudera version.

```
select u.column1, r.column2, AVG(round(r.metric,2)) as avgr from table1 r, table2 u where u.userid= r.userid and r.metric is not null group by u.column1, r.column2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round()` returns `double`, `AVG()` also returns `double`.

Better apply round after AVG:

```
 round(AVG(r.metric),2)
```

If the GUI still displays it incorrectly, convert to `decimal` explicitly:

```
cast(round(AVG(r.metric),2) as decimal(19,2))
```

Comment: Thank you.  It doesn't work on GUI. So I used the other approach you suggested and that worked.